# Using a wireless XBox 360 controller on a PC

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

Can I use a wireless XBox 360 controller on a PC?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, [with an Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-gaming/xbox-360-controller-plugged-to-usb-with-play-and/58087f84-3d2f-4456-bfdd-ccbe28d58d13).

Available for about $27 from Amazon:
[http://www.amazon.com/Xbox-Wireless-Gaming-Receiver-Windows-Pc/dp/B000HZFCT2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000HZFCT2)

The Play and Charge Kit will **NOT** work, as it will only connect to the battery.

Comment: Hello; this answer has been given two years ago.  Any improvement in the meantime that would spare me the purchase of a reciever ?  I'd like to buy [this one](http://www.amazon.com/Xbox-360-Silver-Controller-Play-Charge/dp/B0041HROGG), but I suppose it won't work on PC at all without the damn reciever...

Comment: @Anto nope. You still need a wireless receiver or a wired controller.

Comment: You may also need to follow these instructions: 

Go to device manager and double click on the unknown device. Go to the driver tab and click update driver. Select "Browse my computer for driver software" then "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer", scroll all the way to the bottom and select "Xbox 360 peripherals" then click next. Click next again and say yes to the prompt warning about unverified device.

You can also use the Xbox 360 wireless controller and wireless receiver on macOS -- google it.