# How do I use Wii remote and other controllers for PC games?

Tags: pc, nintendo-wii, controllers

Is there a device or adapter (similar to the one asked about [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/372/using-a-wireless-xbox-360-controller-on-a-pc) for the Xbox 360) to allow me to use my Wii remote and classic controller to control PC games?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The wiimote can be connected to a computer using BlueTooth. There's a tutorial [here](http://www.wiiprojects.org/bluetooth.html) on how to connect the wiimote to the computer via a program called BlueSoleil, which is often bundled with BlueTooth sticks (it was bundled with mine). The computer should recognize it as a joystick.

Also, [this page](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Connect-your-Wiimote-to-your-PC-via-Blueto/step3/Some-Fun-Extras/) lists some interesting things you can do with it. Johnny Lee's project are particularly impressive.

Finally, this [page on the WiimoteProject site](http://www.wiimoteproject.com/bluetooth-and-connectivity-knowledge-center/a-summary-of-windows-bluetooth-stacks-and-their-connection/) has a more in-depth guide for various ways to connect it, not only using BlueSoleil.

Answer (score 3):

The Wii remote communicates via Bluetooth, so you'll need a Bluetooth receiver.

The games you want to play will also have to be capable of reading input from a Bluetooth device.

Answer (score 3):

[GlovePie](http://glovepie.org/) is a great tool that can be used to get input from a wii remote and use it in an existing game.