# Can I connect a wireless Xbox 360 controller to PC with a play & charge cable?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

I have a wireless Xbox 360 controller with its USB charger. Can I use it as a wired controller to play on my PC without buying the [wireless receiver for Windows](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000HZFCT2)?

And if so, where can I find the drivers for Windows 7 64-bit (if available)?

Comment: Hmm.  I was going to say no, but the fact that it's an XBox controller complicates it.  Microsoft might have left in the USB controller for all I know, rather than making it charge-only.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a wireless XBox 360 controller on a PC](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/372/using-a-wireless-xbox-360-controller-on-a-pc)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no way. Microsoft made it so the Play and Charge Kit only receives power. I believe there is some other data that is sent to the controller as well that someone decoded but there is no data sent to the computer from the controller. I will try to dig up a link.

On the other hand, you could just buy a wired controller, those are about as expensive as the wireless receiver, work on both PC and Xbox/Xbox360, and you'd have an extra controller for a friend.

Comment: Thank you... thats a good tip regarding buying a wired controller!

Comment: I use a wired controller for this use, and I know others that do too.  Occasionally they go on sale on Woot or other places, so it is possible to bargain shop.

Comment: Although buying a USB wired controller (USD $25 - $35) may be cost effective, I should point out that buying one USB wireless receiver (~$20 USD) supports connecting up to 4 xbox wireless controllers. So if you already have the wireless controllers this would be the better option.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, if you have an old junked xbox, you can rig it up with the 360 RF receiver and an old USB cable that you don't mind cutting up. after that a small change to the INF file for the drivers your all set using your wireless 360 controller on your pc. Also on a side note, when I first attempted this I didn't compensate for voltage and ended up seriously damaging the usb controller, so don't attempt unless you know a bit about it. Not going to post a how to tutorial here but, you can find near anything on the net. =]

Answer (score 1):

See https://superuser.com/questions/253939/pc-does-not-recognize-xbox-360-controller-connected-through-play-charge-kit.