# Converting a wireless 360 controller to wired

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

I have a wireless Xbox 360 controller that batteries or rechargeables won't work, but the Play & Charge cord still works.

I wanted to wire the controller with a USB from a broken wired controller. I know that the USB cable still works. I know how to wire it so that the controller will take power from the positive and negative (red & black) wires in the USB cord, but I wanted to know how I would wire the data wires (green & white).

I know I could just use the Play & Charge cable, but I enjoy modifying and such. So please don't tell me to just use Play & Charge or to go buy a new one! Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about rewiring a controller.  This is outside the expertise and skillset than can be generally expected of a gaming site.

Comment: That said, perhaps Electrical Engineering would be a better place for this.

Comment: @Frank Hardware mods are [on-topic](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5492/are-questions-about-hardware-mods-on-topic)

Comment: @Robotnik As far as I can tell, that deals with software modding.  I don't think creating or re-wiring a controller is inside our expertise.

Comment: @Frank - Software modding isn't mentioned, it's mostly about hardware, the question in question is about case mods in general. I'm not saying EE wouldn't be a better fit, but currently the consensus is that we do actually accept such questions. And judging from the timecodes between question & answer, it seems that, at least in this case, it does fall pretty well in our expertise-base.

Comment: Just buy a wired controller? surely they are very cheap to buy now?

Comment: If you pulled this off, could you please post it as an answer with a descriptive breakdown of how, hopefully with a few pics to? At the moment there's a great question and an informative answer, but a gap between how the answer solved the question.

Comment: Didn't work. But that was my fault for trying to solder something that small with a chisel tip. I'm not gonna mess up another controller yet but if I break one or something I'll try it again.

Comment: Did this ever come up again?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[The Play and Charge cable does not carry data](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/18508/2259), so buying one wouldn't even work.

I found some [information on a forum](http://www.acidmods.com/forum/index.php?topic=40927.0) about suspected data pins that you could wire up and try (see below), but I can not attest to their correctness.

However, even if there is some USB functionality exposed on those pins, **it might be for some other purpose, with the HID Controller being totally inaccessible**.  I recall trying to use my brother's Play and Charge cable and wireless controller for my PC, and it seemed to [recognize the thing as a USB device, but not a controller](https://superuser.com/q/253939/18931).  If that device was actually the controller, and not some chip in the Play and Charge cable, you might be in for a lot more trouble.

There's a lot of uncertainty on [this forum](http://www.assemblergames.com/forums/showthread.php?39007-Wireless-controller-to-Pc-through-Play-and-charge-kit) some insinuate that Microsoft uses some intentionally broken firmware, because the USB INF file says "NULL Service" (it's probably just a minimal service that negotiates for enough power to charge the battery), so you'll need to get into driver hacks, yadda yadda.  It sounds to me like nobody really has a clue though; maybe you can divine something...

> Acidmods user SycoPthicManiac posted the picture:
>
> > [image: Play and Charge kit PCB connections]
>
> And RDC replied:
>
> > Going off that pic, it's..
> >
> > - 5 V,
> > - D-,
> > - D+,
> > - Charge Status,
> > - 3.3 V,
> > - Charge Status,
> > - Ground

Comment: Thanks a ton dude! This was exactly what I was looking for. It worked without any issues. Soldering took 3 minuets. Thanks again

Comment: @user68763 - If Nicks answer helped, you should mark it as accepted, by clicking the check mark underneath the vote count :-)

Comment: So by wiring those pins into a mini-usb female port and make it available via a small cutout on the controller, I can make my 360 wireless controller wired at will with a simple, standard mini-usb cable?

Comment: In theory.. It isn't easy..

Comment: @MikeBee I'm still skeptical it would work at all.  The controller's USB interface may just be to request sufficient power to charge.