# XBox play and charge kit on PC

Tags: pc, xbox-360, controllers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using a wireless XBox 360 controller on a PC](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/372/using-a-wireless-xbox-360-controller-on-a-pc)

I have heard that it is not possible to use an XBox 360 play and charge kit as a normal controller on Windows since it just charges the batteries but still connects over wifi.

On the other hand in my windows 7 devices view I see "Xbox 360 Wireless Controller via Play & Charge Kit"

Is it still possible to use this as a normal USB controller?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible. You would need to buy the *xbox 360 wireless receiver*.